# MySQL REGEXP No Whitespaces No Numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to return only those rows which colA and colB do not contain a number or a whitespace

Here is my code so far.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE colA REGEXP '[^0-9^\W]' AND colB REGEXP '[^0-9^\W]'
```

given the dataset

```
   colA        colB
---------- ----------
     test |  testB
      33  |  text    <- this is not returned
     blah |  0123A   <- this is returned
```

I am assuming my issue is with my regexp... any help please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well your expression does not work because: 33 is both numbers and you're looking for any non decimal, non whitespace character. so it doesn't include that row in result.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE colA NOT REGEXP '[0-9[:space:]]' AND colB NOT REGEXP '[0-9[:space:]]'
```

ETA: Yea forgot that \whatever does not work

Comment: Ok so how would I then filter out anything that contains a number.. and 'just a space'. Basically I have a data import that contains a lot of invalid values. (names that contain numbers, or are missing completely) I only want to return valid names. so `IF val DOES NOT CONTAIN A NUMBER AND IS NOT BLANK (OR JUST WHITESPACE)` note the columns are 'NOT NULL' flagged. So I cannot check for a null value.

Comment: Note: I re-evaluated the scope, you were correct with this answer.

Comment: Ok, so WHERE colA LIKE "" worked for removing the blank cells (which are not null)

Comment: This work fine

     `WHERE colA not REGEXP '^[0-9]+';`

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support the `\whatever` type escapes for the most part. If you want whitespace, you need to use `[[:space:]]`, which is POSIX syntax. Details on the [regex man page here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score 1):

id suggest to use negate instead: `not regexp '[0-9[:space:]]'`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE colA NOT REGEXP '[0-9[:space:]]' AND colB NOT REGEXP '[0-9[:space:]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another regex you can try is the following: `regexp '[^0-9\s]'`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but give it a try

```
regexp '^[^0-9 ]+$'
```