# Regexp for removing all spaces and digits

Tags: sql, regex, regexp-replace

I am trying to use regular expression in a sql statement to remove all spaces and digits from a string 'text' which may look like

```
1. 000000123456   (No space)
2.  00000 123456 (spaces in the beginning and end of string)
3. 90330000 45  (2 spaces at the end)
```

I have been able to come up with the solutions below so far:

```
select regexp_replace('text','\\s(^[0-9]*)\\s','\\1') 

select regexp_replace('text','[[:blank:]]+[^[0-9]*][[:blank:]]+','\\1')
```

The results I get are:

```
1. 000000123456
2.  00000 123456 
3. 90330000 45
```

I get the text as is. If I try to just remove the digits using

```
regexp_replace('text','^[0-9]*','\\1'),
```

it works fine- all digits get removed and the value results in ''(null). But the text with spaces does not remove the digits nor the space.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `\\1` as the replacement?  This is a capture group, but if you're just looking to _remove_ text, you might not need this.

Comment: Do you want to remove any digits and spaces? So, `00000 123456` will turn into an empty string?

Comment: Please add the expected results for each sample string (include single quotes around the strings for easier testing).

Comment: Yes Wiktor. I wanted the regexp to check if string has only digits and spaces and to evaluate it to '' (blank) value.

Comment: @Wik can this be used as a dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6988503/2943403 or can you find a better one?  Or is Unclear the best close justification?

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry, I could not find any :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using a character class which contains both digits and whitespace:

```
regexp_replace('text', '[0-9\\s]+', '')
```

This should remove all numbers and whitespace.  But, it isn't completely clear what you are trying to do, because you did not show us the numbers in context.